# Can't access Objects from JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I got following JSON object:

```
[{"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 1, "fields": {"value": 4.0, "date": "2016-09-09"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 2, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-01"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 3, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-01"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 4, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-01"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 5, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-01"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 6, "fields": {"value": 5.0, "date": "2016-09-07"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 7, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-28"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 8, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-22"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 9, "fields": {"value": 5.0, "date": "2016-09-16"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 10, "fields": {"value": 5.0, "date": "2016-09-16"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 11, "fields": {"value": 4.0, "date": "2016-09-08"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 12, "fields": {"value": 8.0, "date": "2016-09-22"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 13, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-22"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 14, "fields": {"value": 5.0, "date": "2016-09-01"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 15, "fields": {"value": 8.0, "date": "2016-09-01"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 16, "fields": {"value": 4.0, "date": "2016-09-08"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 17, "fields": {"value": 5.0, "date": "2016-09-09"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 18, "fields": {"value": 5.0, "date": "2016-09-09"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 19, "fields": {"value": 5.0, "date": "2016-09-09"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 20, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-16"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 21, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-16"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 22, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-16"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 23, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-16"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 24, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-16"}}]
```

I want to get the fields "value" and "date". I tried to do it like this (what is the good way normally?) but doesn't work..

```
$http.get("/getcashflow/")
      .success(function(data) {
            for(var cf in data){
                alert(cf.fields.value.data*);
            }
      });
    };
```

Comment: you need to say cf.fields.value. data.* references the original array that was returned. cf references the single object in the array

Comment: @mhodges like now? see original question.

Comment: it should read: alert(cf.fields.value)

Comment: You are also misusing the for...in loop. You should be using a foreach. Meh, this is getting too much for a comment, I will post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you are trying to do, you should be using the `.forEach()` loop, not the `for...in` loop. Using `for...in` on an array, will return you the index of each element, which is not useful in your case, unless you want to refer back to the original array by saying data[cf], which defeats the purpose of using a `for...in` loop in the first place.

```js
var data = [{"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 1, "fields": {"value": 4.0, "date": "2016-09-09"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 2, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-01"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 3, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-01"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 4, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-01"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 5, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-01"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 6, "fields": {"value": 5.0, "date": "2016-09-07"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 7, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-28"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 8, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-22"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 9, "fields": {"value": 5.0, "date": "2016-09-16"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 10, "fields": {"value": 5.0, "date": "2016-09-16"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 11, "fields": {"value": 4.0, "date": "2016-09-08"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 12, "fields": {"value": 8.0, "date": "2016-09-22"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 13, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-22"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 14, "fields": {"value": 5.0, "date": "2016-09-01"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 15, "fields": {"value": 8.0, "date": "2016-09-01"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 16, "fields": {"value": 4.0, "date": "2016-09-08"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 17, "fields": {"value": 5.0, "date": "2016-09-09"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 18, "fields": {"value": 5.0, "date": "2016-09-09"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 19, "fields": {"value": 5.0, "date": "2016-09-09"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 20, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-16"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 21, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-16"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 22, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-16"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 23, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-16"}}, {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 24, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-16"}}];

data.forEach(function (cf) {
    console.log(cf.fields.value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

And in pure JS (ES6) :

```
var input = [
  {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 1, "fields": {"value": 4.0, "date": "2016-09-09"}},
  {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 2, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-01"}},
  {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 3, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-01"}},
  {"model": "pricing.cashflow", "pk": 4, "fields": {"value": 3.0, "date": "2016-09-01"}}
  ];
input.forEach(item => {console.log("value -> " + item.fields.value + " and date -> " + item.fields.date)}); 

// value -> 4 and date -> 2016-09-09
// value -> 3 and date -> 2016-09-01
// value -> 3 and date -> 2016-09-01
// value -> 3 and date -> 2016-09-01
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, JSON deserializes as an object. To access the members of that object use the dot accessor. In your case the value you are looking for would be accessible as `data[cf].fields.value.data`

Note that the `for in` loop returns the keys of the object or array, not the actual values. (for example in the first iteration of the loop, cf is equal to zero, not the first object)

```
$http.get("/getcashflow/")
      .success(function(data) {
            for(var cf in data){
                alert(data[cf].fields.value.data);
            }
      });
    };
```